# How to mock reducers/store on react-testing-library for all tests

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

In my tests I normally mock each and every dispatch/selector needed for each specific test. But I have one prop on my `reducers/store` that applies to almost all components. I always import it directly from the `reducers/store`

```
import { history } from 'reducers/store';
```

Because this is not exactly specific to each test. How can I mock that for *all* tests? I cannot use a `beforeAll` because I am not talking about just a specific set in one component. I would like this mocked throughout all the tests in the entire application.

I already have a similar scenario for external libraries such as react-router. In this case, I only had to add a new file `react-router` inside the `__mocks__` folder. But I tried doing something similar to the store with

```
__mocks__
  reducers
    store.js
```

But that didn't work.

Since I already mock each and every dispatch and selector as needed, my store only need to have the history inside of it.

How am I able to mock this to the entire application?

Comment: [The documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) says it should be `__mocks__` (plural)

Comment: sorry, typo on the question...

Comment: May I suggest you to create an example of what's not working in an isolated environment for example in codesandbox?